# How do I open an iframe when you click on a link?

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I started coding a browser based on iframes but I dont know how to open the link as an iframe.

I really dont know how to get the link to open.

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also see how to provide a [mre]. Someone can help you more easily when the code is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but depending on which conext and window you want the iframe to be in, here are some ways to open a link as an iframe:

- If you want to open an iframe window in current window in the current page context (*in the current page context* means parent of the iframe is the current window)

Attach a click event listener to the link you wish to open as an iframe. When the link is clicked, create a new  element dynamically using JavaScript. Set the *src* attribute of the  element to the URL of the link. Append the newly created  element to the desired location in the DOM.

Here is an example that demonstrates this approach:

```js
const link = document.getElementById('link')
function handleLinkClick() {
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  iframe.src = 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik'
  iframe.width = '500'
  iframe.height = '500'
  document.body.appendChild(iframe)
}
```

```html
<a id="link" onclick="handleLinkClick()">click to open this link</a>
```

- If you want to open an iframe within a new tab while remaining within the current page context

This is impossible. An iframe is restricted to the boundaries of the current page and cannot be opened outside of it.

- If you want to open an iframe window in a new tab

Open a new window and wrap the content within iframe. However, the iframe within the new tab will be in the context of the new window, separate from the current window.

EDIT:

If you want to open the link as a full-page iframe, you can achieve this by setting the height and width of the iframe to cover the entire page, and using CSS *position:absolute* to overlay the iframe on top of the page content.

If you want to open all links like this, you can provide a close button or use tabs to allow users to navigate between different iframes.

example:

```js
const links = {
    link1: 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik',
  link2: 'https://example.org/'
}

let currentIframeId;
// top left red button to close the full page iframe
const closeBtn = document.createElement('button');
closeBtn.classList.add('close-btn')
closeBtn.onclick = handleCloseIFrame
closeBtn.innerText = '+'

function handleLinkClick(index) {
    currentIframeId = index;
    const link = links[index]
    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
  iframe.src = link
  iframe.classList.add('full-page-iframe', index)
  document.body.appendChild(iframe)
  setCloseBtVisibility(true)
}

// control the visibility of the close button
function setCloseBtVisibility(visible) {
    if(visible) {
    document.body.appendChild(closeBtn)
  }else {
   document.body.removeChild(closeBtn);
  }
}

function handleCloseIFrame() {
    const iframe = document.querySelector(`.${currentIframeId}`);
  document.body.removeChild(iframe)
  setCloseBtVisibility(false)
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

.link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.full-page-iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: none;
}

.disappear {
  display: none;
}

.close-btn{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="link1" class="link" onclick="handleLinkClick('link1')">click to open this link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="link2" class="link" onclick="handleLinkClick('link2')">click to open this link 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make all links open as an iframe? like when you search for something and you click the link it will open as a full page iframe?